# How to parse a C string with Bison

Tags: c, bison

I have a string in a C file like this:

```
char *test = "print x";
```

I want to parse that with a Bison parser I've written. Is it possible?

Comment: Most likely yes. What have you tried so far? What isn't working?

Comment: You need to configure your lexical analyzer so that it will read from the string, tokenizing it, and reporting EOF (via the return value 0) when it reaches the end.  You probably need an initialization function and the `yylex()` code to read from what the initialization set.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bison parsers don't read input at all. They simply obtains a series of tokens by repeatedly calling `yylex`. (Or, with modern bison, you can create a "push parser" which is given tokens in successive calls.) So whatever implements `yylex` is responsible for the input.

If you use `flex` to create a lexical scanner, you can use `yy_scan_string` (or `yy_scan_bytes` if you know how long the string is) to scan a string instead of scanning from a file. See the [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#Scanning-Strings) for details on these functions.

For a simple example, you could put the following two functions at the end of your `flex` definition file, after the second `%%`:

```
void set_input_string(const char* in) {
  yy_scan_string(in);
}

void end_lexical_scan(void) {
  yy_delete_buffer(YY_CURRENT_BUFFER);
}
```

And put this at the end of your bison definition file, again after the second `%%`:

```
/* Declarations */
void set_input_string(const char* in);
void end_lexical_scan(void);

/* This function parses a string */
int parse_string(const char* in) {
  set_input_string(in);
  int rv = yyparse();
  end_lexical_scan();
  return rv;
}
```

Then you can declare and use `parse_string` to parse a string.

Comment: Getting this error:  `error: use of undeclared identifier 'yy_free_buffer'`

Comment: @TejGop: Sorry, memory spasm. It's `yy_delete_buffer`. Fixed the answer. See the [docs](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#Multiple-Input-Buffers)

Comment: Is there any way of doing this (reading from a string) while in the middle of reading from a file without restarting bison's parse state? I can easily have flex read from a string, but when it does, bison for some reason starts up a whole new parse stack rather than continuing the existing one.

Comment: @velocirabbit: sure, but you need to *ask a question*. ([ask].) Please show what you tried.